# Access local workstation remotely

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, internet, nat

I am using a linux box with dynamic IP.

I need to access the box from outside.

"Access" means many things but to begin with I just need to be and to ping the box externally.

The default INPUT policy is ACCEPT but it's not allowing pings from outside:

```
$ sudo iptables -L -v -n --line-numbers

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 16649 packets, 11M bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 17815 packets, 2006K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I have read about NAT and port forwarding but I thought these are only necessary if accessing particular services on the box (e.g. mail, web, etc)?

I have also seen mention of DynDNS (dyn.com) but not sure whether such a service is necessary just to ping a box?

Comment: You should look up, in Google, *reverse tunnel* and *OpenVPN*. Both solve your problem.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Okay. Let me check them out. Thanks.